# Java Stream Maintain Map order generated by Collectors.groupingBy()

Tags: java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a List of data of type String, trying to get the count of each string as `Map<String, Long>`

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList();
dataList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "z", "c", "b", "a"}));
System.out.println(dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting())));
```

Output is `{a=2, b=2, c=1, z=1}`. I wanted the output to maintain the order as provided in list. Like, `{a=2, z=1, c=1, b=2}`.

`LinkedHashMap` will maintain the order, but not sure how to user `Collectors.groupingBy()` to cast output to `LinkedHashMap`.

Trying to solve the problem using Java8-stream

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you should use `groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier, Supplier<M> mapFactory,Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)` function:

**Code example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList();
        dataList.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "z", "c", "b", "a"));
        System.out.println(dataList.stream().collect(groupingBy(w -> w, (Supplier<LinkedHashMap<String, Long>>) LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting())));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{a=2, z=1, c=1, b=1}
```

References:[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Comment: The type cast `(Supplier<LinkedHashMap<String, Long>>)` should not be necessary. A simple `dataList.stream().collect(groupingBy(w -> w, LinkedHashMap::new, counting()))` should do…

Answer (score 2):

Per JB Nizet
`dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))`

Answer (score 0):

Not as simple as the given solutions, but just for illustration: you can use a TreeMap as well, with a suitable Comparator, like:

```
List<Character> list = Arrays.asList('q', 'a', 'z', 'c', 'b', 'z', 'a');
Comparator<Character> comp = Comparator.comparing(list::indexOf);
Map<Character, Long> map = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, () -> new TreeMap<>(comp), counting()))
;
System.out.println(map);
```